# How better can I write this IF Formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula

I have a IF formula have the above error.  The formula is below.  I might need to use something else but I'm new at this.

```
=IF(F10<=AB2,"GREAT",IF(F10<=AB3,"GOOD",IF(F10<=AB4,"NEEDS WORK"), IF(F10<=AB5,"POOR",IF(F10<=AB6,"CONCERN"))))
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the below:

```
GREAT            >4%
GOOD            4-5%
NEEDS WORK      5-6%
POOR            7-8%
CONCERN         >9%
```

Please help. Deb

In the previous email.

Comment: "In the previous email"?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the closing parentheses. And there are some issues in your description. Assuming that you meant "GREAT <4%" instead of ">4%".

Here's the corrected formula for you:

```
=IF(F10<=AB2,"GREAT",IF(F10<=AB3,"GOOD",IF(F10<=AB4,"NEEDS WORK", IF(F10<=AB5,"POOR",IF(F10>=AB6,"CONCERN","")))))
```

Comment: Hi Timmy, I have added the updated formula and it is not showing the Text as Poor.  Do you have any secret.  I do have unconditionally formatting here also.

Comment: Did you set you AB5 to 9%?

Comment: So sorry. I think I'm lost it.

Comment: I have the formula as this.

Comment: =if(F10<=AB2,"GREAT",IF(F10<=AB3,"GOOD",IF(F10<=AB4,"NEEDS WORK",IF(F10<=AB5,"POOR",IF(F10>=AB6,"CONCERN")))))

Comment: I changed the search table to the below: GREAT 4.00%
GOOD 5.00%
NEEDS WORK 6.00%
POOR 8.00%
CONCERN 9.00%

Answer (score 0):

A good apprach is to keep all values in a separate 2-column sheet range, such as below:

[image]

Then we can use the formula

```
=INDEX(FILTER(J5:J10, I5:I10>=L5), 1)
```

where L5 cell contains a test value.